# Is there a creature half dragon and half horse?

Tags: system-agnostic, monsters

Is there a specific such creature, with a name for it and description, in any lore or game?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about a role-playing game.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In D&D 3/3.5e there is a creature called a Dragonnel (p.151-152 of the Draconomicon).  While not strictly a half-horse/half-dragon it serves the purpose being essentially a winged steed that very much looks like a scaly horse with dragon wings.  It also has a little bit more background then the templates below.

Both D&D 3.x and Pathfinder have the half-dragon template which entirely applies to horses [D20SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/halfDragon.htm)/[Pathfinder SRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/half-dragon).

Pathfinder Bestiary 2 also has a creature called a [Dragon Horse](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/magical-beasts/dragon-horse) however this is not a draconic creature but merely a horse that flies.  The Dragon Horse is also in the Tome of Horrors (Complete for Pathfinder rules, [Revised](http://www.scribd.com/doc/49226996/Tome-of-Horrors-Revised)(p.167) for D&D rules).  It looks like the Bestiary 2 version is probably based partially off of this and the original Gary Gygax version.

In Dragon Magic, there is another dragon/horse hybrid that might work: the Drakkensteed.  Best link I could find talking about it is [here](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?t=162593).

Comment: Here's a link to a wiki containing an Dragonnel image: http://kahdnd.pbworks.com/w/page/5588862/Dragonnel

Answer (score 11):

The **[Qilin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qilin)** or **Kirin** is a creature of Chinese mythology that has been described in various ways, one of which is a half-dragon, half-horse or half-deer.

The "[Ki-rin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ki-rin_%28Dungeons_%26_Dragons%29)" appears in the (A)D&D monster manuals as early as 1st edition AD&D's *Monster Manual* (1977), where it is depicted as a scaled, Chinese-dragon-headed, hoofed equine that flies but is wingless (much like Chinese dragons). In D&D they are very rare and very intelligent, and as likely to serve as mounts as Western unicorns, i.e., not very often at all.

Answer (score -2):

sounds like something out of Gamma world O_O 
Though, from some checks around... there is at least a drawing someone made based on... apparently, the same topic that popped up for a discussion.  You can see the [image here](http://forum.rpg.net/showthread.php?178349-ART-Half-Dragon-Half-Horse) if you want something to start with.  Also, from another page talking about a person who [rides a half-dragon/half-horse](http://therafimrpg.wikidot.com/eligor) 
If the Valor d10 game was out, that could most likely be accomplished within 5 min for a monster make. 
But I do agree from most people's perspective... how would that happen?